# Android Maps v2 - Info Window click not working despite listener present

Tags: android, kotlin, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get a `Toast` to appear depending on which `InfoWindow` was clicked. I've already implemented the click listeners for each `InfoWindow` but for reason none of them do anything when clicked. I also tried 2 different methods individually (`mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener`) and (`override fun onInfoWindowClick`) but still had no success.

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment(), GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    private lateinit var mGoogleMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var mMapView: MapView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)

        mMapView = v.map_location
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this)

        return v
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap
        mGoogleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL


        val locationA = LatLng(44.862390, -0.550287)
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(locationA)
                .title("Location A")
        )

        val locationB = LatLng(44.863089, -0.551417)
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(locationB)
                .title("Location B")
        )

        mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener { marker ->
            if (marker.equals(locationA)) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if (marker.equals(locationB)) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(44.862716, -0.550763), 18f)
    }

    override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker?) {
        if (marker != null) {
            if (marker.id == "locationA") {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else if (marker.id == "locationB") {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mMapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mMapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mMapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mMapView.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing LatLng with Marker, it cannot works.

you should for example compare the marker titles:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap
    mGoogleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL


    val locationA = LatLng(44.862390, -0.550287)
    // markerA is a variable of your fragment
    markerA = mGoogleMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(locationA)
            .title("Location A")
    )

    val locationB = LatLng(44.863089, -0.551417)
    // markerB is a variable of your fragment
    markerB = mGoogleMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(locationB)
            .title("Location B")
    )

    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener { marker ->
        onMarkerClick(marker)
    }

    val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(44.862716, -0.550763), 18f)
}

override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker?) {
    if (marker != null) {
        onMarkerClick(marker)
    }
}

private fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker) {
        if (marker.id == markerA.id) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (marker.id == markerB.id) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this go? In `mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener` or `override fun onInfoWindowClick`?

Comment: I've just tried your answer and it doesn't work. Bear in mind that I want the `Toast` to appear when I click the `InfoWindow` not the `Marker`.

Comment: look at the edition of onMarkerClick method i made because it was wrong comparaison

Comment: It is not a good idea to match the marker's title in case there are at least 2 markers that have the same name. Can you please show me how to check for the markers `position`? I already tried `if (marker.position == locationA) {...` but I get an unresolved reference error.

Comment: @MacaronLover i agree with you it's not a good way to compare markers by name. you can use marker id or tag of marker returned by addMarker method with this: val markerA = mGoogleMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(locationB)
            .title("Location B")
    )

Comment: @MacaronLover i've edited the response with two instance variable for markerA and B, you can also use a list of markers or a map<string, marker> where the key is the marker id.